# How do I write prolog program which adds up only the positive numbers?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to learn prolog and this is a small program I need, however, I cannot figure out how to do this.

Could anyone help me out please?

We have possum(S, K).

Here S is a list of numbers.
K is the sum of the positive numbers.

?- possum([5,-1,3],K).

Should print out: K = 8.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
possum(L, X) :- include(<(0), L, P), sum_list(P, X).
```

Test:

```
?- possum([5, -1, 3], X).
X = 8.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You were a BIG help!